# how to remove quarter turn tap valve with no flat parts

Tags: plumbing, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to remove a quarter turn tap valve from a bathroom sink mixer tap.  All the guides I've found expect there to be a hexagonal part on the valve to use a spanner to unscrew it, but this one is just round.  I've tried pulling it outwards with a spanner behind the lip at the top, but it hasn't shifted.  Any ideas on how to get this out?

[image: quarter turn valve]

[image: whole tap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a deep socket or box spanner (image below) to get to the large hexagon that is at the bottom of the hole in the top picture - visible clearer in the image if you zoom in.

[image]